# Open many local HTML files IN ORDER in Firefox

Tags: nautilus, firefox, files, html

I have 200+ HTML files stored locally that I need to open in Firefox **in order of the filename**, so that I can use the Universal Print extension to create a PDF.

If I do a multi-select in Nautilus and select "open with Firefox", they get opened in a random order.

Here's a sample filename: `saved_resource(48).html`

All the other files have exactly the same name, just with a different number in the parenthases.

Am I missing something obvious here?

---

Alternatively, if there exists a utility to convert all the HTML files to a PDF, that would work as well...

Comment: The 'wkhtmltopdf' package converts htmlfiles to PDF, and is in the Ubuntu repositories. It's a command-line application, so you can simply script the order you want the PDFs created.

Comment: @user535733 - Looks promising, but the PDF that it renders is just plain white pages.